# Implementing MonadError through ExceptT

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Can one reasonably implement `MonadError` threw a newtype wrapping `ExceptT`? So far I have:

```
newtype BlahT e m a = BlahT (ExceptT e m a) deriving newtype (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

instance MonadError e m => MonadError e (BlahT e' m) where
  throwError = BlahT . ExceptT . (Right <$>) . throwError
  catchError = _ -- ???
```

I know `catchError = const` will compile, but that's not what I want to do. I basically (think I) want `catchError` in the case of `ExceptT` being a "`Right`" to behave like `catchError` would on the underlying monad, but in the case of "`Left`" `catchError` does nothing (we'll check have to check the return of `ExceptT` in this case).

I've bashed my head against this but have got stuck wrestling with the type checker. Is there actually a sensible implementation of `catchError` here or is what I'm trying to do impossible for some reason?

Comment: ExceptT already has an instance for MonadError. In order to implement MonadError for your newtype, you'll have to decide how you want it to behave differently from the ordinary ExceptT instance. If you don't want it to behave differently at all, then just implement MonadError via newtype deriving.

Comment: @amalloy it doesn't have the above instance. It only has an instance for `Monad m => MonadError e (ExceptT e m)` (note the lack of `e'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the type of `catch`:

```
catch :: m a -> (e -> m a) -> m a
```

And specialized to `BlahT e m`:

```
catch :: BlahT e m a -> (e -> BlahT e m a) -> BlahT e m a
```

unfold `BlahT e m a = m (Either e a)`

```
catch :: m (Either e a) -> (e -> m (Either e a)) -> m (Either e a)
```

which is merely a specialization of `catch` of the underlying monad `m`.
So you can implement `BlahT`'s `catch` as `coerce` of `m`'s `catch`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, DerivingVia, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, UndecidableInstances, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module E where

import Control.Monad.Except
import Data.Coerce

newtype BlahT e m a = BlahT (ExceptT e m a) deriving newtype (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

type Catch e m a = m a -> (e -> m a) -> m a

instance MonadError e m => MonadError e (BlahT e' m) where
  throwError = BlahT . ExceptT . (Right <$>) . throwError
  catchError = (coerce :: Catch e m (Either e' a) -> Catch e (BlahT e' m) a) catchError
```